# Переключатели на JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$('.btn-payment__type').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('btn-payment__type--active').siblings().removeClass('btn-payment--active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-payment__type btn-payment__type--active">MasterCard</button>
<button class="btn-payment__type">MasterCard</button>
<button class="btn-payment__type">MasterCard</button>
```

Есть следующий код, по идее при клике на баттон должен добавляться класс btn-payment__type--active и убираться у другого, но происходит совсем иначе, класс добавляется, но не убирается с соседнего. Почему так?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Вы пытаетесь убрать класс `btn-payment--active`, а добавляете `btn-payment__type--active`. Синтаксическая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Решение на чистом js

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-payment__type');

[...btn].forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    evt.preventDefault;
    let current = document.querySelector('.btn-payment__type--active');
    current.classList.remove('btn-payment__type--active')
    element.classList.add('btn-payment__type--active')
  })
})
```

```css
.btn-payment__type--active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-payment__type btn-payment__type--active">MasterCard</button> 
<button class="btn-payment__type">MasterCard</button> 
<button class="btn-payment__type">MasterCard</button>
```